# Bypass the login screen and redirect the user to community

Tags: community, authenticate

I have 2 different org and both org have same user registered in both org with same email and fedrationid. Now my requirement is when a user log into one community and he try top redirect from 1st community to the 2 community , he should not be asked for login as he is already resisted.

How can we login to a community without username & password, authenticate user from url parameter. I want to bypass the login screen and redirect the user to community by authenticate he/she by using any other mechanism. We can't marked community as public.

> eg: passing required information in url and authenticate and redirect the user through an apex class.

Comment: Where are the users authenticated - in Salesforce or using another Authorisation provider?

Comment: In salesforce itself.